# JMeter - How to use few sets of variables from csv file in one post request?

Tags: csv, jmeter, http-post

Is it possible to run request with 1000 sets of lat,lon from csv file.
This should be in one POST request.
Request looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "lat": ${random_lat},
      "lon": ${random_lon}
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "lat": ${random_lat},
      "lon": ${random_lon}
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "lat": ${random_lat},
      "lon": ${random_lon}
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

csv file looks like this:

```
51.3054489472673,-117.2031134800404
54.5883543433925,-98.0338493138702
58.2433547520569,-115.0488099947172
50.3905178887011,-138.4806899125170
41.8205185112055,-115.7196913326360
55.5866340199235,-95.6419879448747
```

The request should look like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "lat": 51.3054489472673,
      "lon": -117.2031134800404
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "lat": 54.5883543433925,
      "lon": -98.0338493138702
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "lat": 58.2433547520569,
      "lon": -115.0488099947172
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I got this but all sets of lat,lon was with first row from csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You need to fetch 'lat' & 'lon' values from the CSV file that has lan & lon separated by line and use all lat & lon in the single request.

**Solution:**
There are different ways to achieve this scenario. But the most reliable and easiest way is to use 'Beanshell Sampler' element of JMeter:

- Add Beanshell sampler as first request in your thread group and add following code: [image]

String path = "C:/Users/ravsharma/Desktop/ABC1.csv";

File file = new File(path);

BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = null;

Integer i = 1;

while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {

System.out.println(line);

String[] lat_lon = line.split(",");

vars.put("random_lat" + i, lat_lon[0]);

vars.put("random_lon" + i, lat_lon[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A00Zw.jpg));

i++;

}

bufRdr.close();

- This code will fetch lat & lon from your csv file.
- You can further use these variables as ${random_lat1}, ${random_lon1}, ${random_lat2},${random_lon2}... in your POST request.

Here are few tips to [Optimize Your JMeter Test Plan](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/10/8-tips-for-optimizing-jmeter-test-plans/)

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. Thank you. But This is a bit hard if I have 1000 sets of lat,lon.. and I have to set these variables ${random_lat1}, ${random_lon1}, ${random_lat2},${random_lon2}... ${random_lat1000},${random_lon1000} in my POST request.

Comment: Do you know some way to automate iterate of those varaiables in POST request?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ideal use case for the [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter)

1. If you don't have Random CSV Data Set Config in your JMeter you can install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. Place the Random CSV Data Set Config and configure it in pretty much the same way you do it for "normal" CSV Data Set Config

   [image: JMeter Random CSV Data Set Config]

   Make sure that `Random order` box is ticked
3. That's it, you can now use reference Variable names anywhere in the Thread Group and they will contain random cells from your CSV data

   [image: Random CSV Data Set Config in action]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways which I can think of.

1- Use multiple csv for input variables.

2-Use single csv for input variables.

3- Use random csv data set config or jp@gc - Variables from csv.

So, plan will be..
Thread Group>CSV Data Set Config>HTTP Request>View Results Tree

I am showing option 2, single csv,place variables like shown below:-

random_lat1,    random_lon1,    random_lat2,    random_lon2,    random_lat3,    random_lon3

51.30544895,    -117.2031135,   58.24335475,    -115.04881, 41.82051851,    -115.7196913

......

.......

So, first run will get all the values in a single request for multiple variables.

[image: Multiple Values in Single Request]

If you want to go vertically for variables set values in csv then choose option 3 and use [jp@gc - Variables from CSV files](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/VariablesFromCSV/)

But this requires change in json accordingly as shown below:-

{
      "id": "1",
      "lat": ${random_lat**1**},
      "lon": ${random_lon**1**}
    }
 {
      "id": "2",
      "lat": ${random_lat**2**},
      "lon": ${random_lon**2**}
    }
....

Hope it will help you with your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

@Ravi Sharma - I still don't know how to do it in JMeter. So I wrote python script to generate it, then I manually paste the output to body data. Thank you guys for your help.

```
filename = "C:/Users/r/data/file_to_save.csv"

range1 = 1000
i = 0
with open(filename, 'a') as ff:
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i < range1:
            text="    {\n\
        \"entity_id\": \"%i\",\n\
        \"lat\": ${random_lat%i},\n\
        \"lon\": ${random_lon%i}\n\
    },\n" % (i, i, i)
        else:
            break
        ff.write(text)
ff.close()
```